# Perform "actions" in status bar widget

Tags: odoo, action, statusbar, odoo-8

I have a field with a status bar widget, and I want if I press a button in the statusbar a function is launched, (something like onchange), some help??

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly the onchange or you can extend the statusbar widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

xml file

```
<button name="action_draft" type="object"
                            string="Reset to draft"
                            states="confirm"/>
<button name="action_confirm" type="object"
                                    string="Confirm" states="draft"
                                    class="oe_highlight"/>
<field name="state" widget="statusbar"/>
```

.py file

```
def action_draft(self):
    self.state = 'draft'

def action_confirm(self):
    self.state = 'confirm'
```